# extraneous space around italics and bolds in manpage?

Tags: linux, manpage, groff, troff

I am writing a man page. I am displaying only with `man -l filename.man`.

I am running into an issue where my text is displaying as:

`file/path/[ option ]`

Where I would like it to display as:

`file/path/[option]`.

The offending lines of text (code?) look like:

```
.\" filename.man

The filepath is /file/path/[
.I option
], and it contains files.
```

I am extremely new to formatting with [gnt]roff, and appreciate any pointers or recommended readings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definite guide to groff is [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/). I recommend the pdf for easy searching. It includes chapter 5.17.1 *Changing Fonts* that explains `\f`. Note there are at least 2 alternatives. The first uses `\c` to stop further output at the end of a line:

```
The filepath is /file/path/[\c
.I option\c
], and it contains files.
```

but the following is the preferred method, using a macro `RI` (roman-italic) provided specially for the purpose of joining "words" in an alternating roman then italic font:

```
The filepath is 
.RI /file/path/[ option ],
and it contains files.
```

See the pdf chapter 4.1.3 *Macros to set fonts*, or the man page for `groff_man` (the man macros, also at [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Man-font-macros.html#Man-font-macros))

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the `\fI <text> \fR` in line style tags in place of the `.I` tags at the start of the line. In your code,

```
.\" filename.man

The filepath is /file/path/[\fIoption\fR], and it contains files.
```

I don't know why, and would appreciate comments or edits explaining the difference or linking to useful documentation.